# Python 3 utf-8 encoding seem to be wrong?

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x

I've messed in the past with Python 3.2 but now I face a somewhat confusing situation about utf-8 encoding in python.
For example, say I have this piece of code:

```
'א'.encode()
```

The result is `b'\xd7\x90'` (or `0xD790`), this, however, is wrong: the utf-8 encoding of the Hebrew character Alef is supposed to be `0x5D0`.
However, using utf-16 as the encoding returns the correct hex value, with a prefix of `0xFFFE`:

```
'א'.encode('utf-16')
```

this returns `b'\xff\xfe\xd0\x05'`.

I feel as if I'm missing something fundamental in my understanding,
SO users, please help educate me!

Comment: That is the correct UTF-8 encoding for that codepoint, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05D0/index.htm

Comment: Since you're confusing very basic Unicode terms (codepoints and encodings), you urgently need to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Ah, another victim of Windows's misleading description of UTF-16LE as "Unicode"...

Answer (score 8):

The [unicode *codepoint* of א is U+05D0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05D0/index.htm), or `101 1101 0000` in binary. The UTF-8 encoding of an 11-bit codepoint ABCDEFGHIJK [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

```
110A BCDE  10FG HIJK
# i.e.
1101 0111  1001 0000 # binary
 d    7     9    0   # hex
```

or, in Python notation, `b'\xd7\x90'`.

Answer (score 6):

`0x5d0` is not an encoding at all; it is simply a number. Yes, HEBREW LETTER ALEF is U+05D0, but UTF-8 is not a transcription of the codepoint to bytes. Instead, it uses a certain fixed set of bits in the MSbs of each byte, and populates the LSbs with a variable number of bits from the codepoint value.

```
0x5d0 = 101 1101 0000
      = 10111 010000
```

Inserting into [110xxxxx 10xxxxxx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) we get:

```
11010111 10010000 = 0xd7 0x90
```

Comment: Re: *transcription of the codepoint to bytes*: It kind of is (especially if you substitute *transcription* with *encoding*). I'd say it's not a *plain* transcription (that would be UCS-4).

Answer (score 4):

No, the *unicode codepoint* for `א` is 0x5d0:

```
print("%x" % ord('א'))  
# '5d0'
```

When you encode it to `utf-8` you get one possible way of representing that specific codepoint. `utf-16` would be another way to represent it, it represents each codepoints using 2 bytes. The reason why you get the it prefixed with `\xff\xfe` is that `encode('utf-16')` generates a byte order mark (BOM). If you explicitely specify the byte ordering, then it won't be generated:

```
>>> a='א'
>>> a.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfe\xd0\x05'
>>> a.encode('utf-16-le')
b'\xd0\x05'
>>> a.encode('utf-16-be')
b'\x05\xd0'
```